# How to store nested data in mongoDB using mongoosejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

> Sample data which I want to store in mongodb. *Using postman for checking the
> API.*

```
{
  "id": "242kd",
  "user_id": "123gsgshsghgshgs6",
  "product_id_quantity": [
    {
      "product_id": 8,
      "quantity": 2
    },
    {
      "product_id": 7,
      "quantity": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

> Controller code: **cartController.js**

```
  exports.createCart = (req, res, next) => {
  const productIdQuantity = new productIdQuantitySchema({
    product_id: req.body.product_id_quantity.product_id,
    quantity: req.body.product_id_quantity.quantity,
  })
  const cart = new Cart({
    userId: req.body.user_id,
    product_id_quantity: [productIdQuantity],
  });
  cart.save().then(result => {
    res.status(201).json({
      message: "Cart Created!",
      result: result
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: err+"Error occuer at the time of cart creation!"
    });
  });
}
```

> Model code: **cartModel.js**

```
const productIdQuantitySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  id: String,
  product_id: { type: String, required: true },
  quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
});

const cartSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  id: String,
  userId: { type: String, required: true },
  product_id_quantity: productIdQuantitySchema,
});
```

> **Error getting on postmant**

```
{
    "message": "ValidationError: product_id_quantity: Cast to Embedded failed for value \"[ { _id: new ObjectId(\"643c330dd33750a122282f3f\") } ]\" (type Array) at path \"product_id_quantity\" because of \"ObjectExpectedError\"Error occuer at the time of cart creation!"
}
```

> Postman Screen shoot:

[image]

Could you please help me what need to be change on the code (controller/model) or in postman body or anywhere else.

Comment: try changing to array ?`product_id_quantity: [productIdQuantitySchema],`

Comment: Hi @cmgchess Getting same ValidationError error, in different way. **{
    "message": "ValidationError: product_id_quantity.0.quantity: Path `quantity` is required., product_id_quantity.0.product_id: Path `product_id` is required.Error occuer at the time of cart creation!"
}**

Comment: `req.body.product_id_quantity` is an array. so map it and create an array of objects and pass into model? `const product_id_quantity =  req.body.product_id_quantity.map(item => ({ product_id: item.product_id, quantity: item.quantity }));` and in new Cart `product_id_quantity: productIdQuantity`

Comment: Hi @cmgchess Thanks for the quick response. It's working. Note: Update the constant value in your comment to **productIdQuantity** insted of **product_id_quantity**

Comment: awesome should i give as an answer or do you write yourself

Comment: It's your @cmgchess, if you have time you can write else i have to write myself. Thanks for  your time and qick response

Comment: by the way can you check if `product_id_quantity: req.body.product_id_quantity` . the map looks unnecessary since there is no change in structure or field names

Answer (score 0):

A few issues in your code

1. Since you are passing an array of `product_id_quantity` you should modify the `cartSchema` so that it takes an array of items

```js
const cartSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  id: String,
  userId: { type: String, required: true },
  product_id_quantity: [productIdQuantitySchema],
});
```

2. In your controller you are trying to access like  `req.body.product_id_quantity.product_id` but `req.body.product_id_quantity` is an array so you cannot directly access properties. Since it is the same structure as your schema what you can do is take that array and pass it directly into your Cart model

```js
  const cart = new Cart({
    userId: req.body.user_id,
    product_id_quantity: req.body.product_id_quantity
  });
```